# Raspberry pi 3b trying to add python directories to open cv. Wont compile get " constant 1_MAGIC_VAL (cname=cv : : 1 : :MAGIC_VAL) already exists

Tags: python, opencv, pi

I have gotten  to the 2 files shown after the error
One of them is read only.
The other one

```
[CMakeFiles/Makefile2:13508:modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all]
```

So that I could play with if i know knew what to do .
I got it to compile 81% before I hit this wall.
Thanks